# Different location for a specific path

Tags: node.js, nginx, server-side-rendering

im trying to serve a different location based on a specific path structure and user agent to serve dynamic rendering to crawler.

What i needs is that every path following this structure: /user/*/artwork/* and with a user agent of any bot to serve a nodejs express app with reverse proxy, everything else just send to the root of a static html dir.

Here what i tried with no success:

```
server {

  index index.html;
  server_name domain.app;

  location  ~/user/(.*)/artwork/(.*) {
        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($uri ~ "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff)") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        if ($prerender = 1) {
            set $prerender "localhost:3010";
            proxy_pass http://$prerender;
        }

        root /home/user/domain.app/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

  location / {
    root /home/user/domain.app/dist;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
 if ($host = domain.app) {
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 } # managed by Certbot

 listen 80 default_server;
 server_name domain.app;
 return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

It doesnt seem to serve anything different when its a bot user agent (using Googlebot user agent on google chrome Network condition setting)

EDIT:

I made it this way and its working:

```
server {

  index index.html;  
  server_name domain.app;

  location ~*/robots.txt {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3010;
  }

  location ~*/user/(.*)/artwork/(.*) {

        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest\/0\.|pinterestbot|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|whatsapp>
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }
        if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if ($prerender = 1) {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3010;
            break;
        }

        root /home/user/domain.app/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    }

   location / {
    root /home/user/domain.app/dist;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

   listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
  if ($host = domain.app) {
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name domain.app;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

This is working but probably a bit messy.

For some reasons, set $prerender "localhost:3010"; and then using $prerender proxy_pass http://$prerender; wasn't working so i use it directly like this: proxy_pass http://localhost:3010;

If anyone have advice to make it beter i would be happy to clean it up :)